# How can my background.js for a Chrome extension investigate the content of a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension which shall conditionally do actions.
Therefore, it shall investigate the DOM for all new tabs. In case the title tab matches, it shall take further actions and isolate this particular tab in a separate Chrome window.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() {
/* 
    Multiple Tasks:
    1.  Check whether title tag matches the CPD Teamcenter title and custom success tab does not exist
    2.  If yes, trigger three actions:
        a.  move tab to new Chrome window
        b.  call external application to hide the window with the isolated tab
        c.  add custom success tag to identify that this was already processed
*/

const COMPARESTRING = "My Tab Title"

var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
alert(title.innerHTML)

if (title.innerHTML === COMPARESTRING) {
    return "Match. :-)";
} else {
    return "No match. :-(";
}

});
```

This very simple alert is already non-functional. It seems to investigate the background.html instead of the content of a new tab. What is required to get into the context of the HTML content of the new tab?

Comment: You have 3 equals signs on the if.

Comment: The background script can't access DOM of web page tabs, only a content script can do it, see the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). However in this case you don't need DOM, just read [the `tab` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated) directly. As for adding a custom tag, you can save the tab id in a global array/object.

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm This is now working, but I see that the onUpdated Listener triggers 4x when I enter a new URL, and 3x when I refresh the existing URL. Can I reduce this to the very final update event?

Comment: Can't help without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm.  Sure.  This question here is answered.  I filed a new one.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504452/chrome-tabs-onupdated-addlistener-triggers-multiple-times