# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener triggers multiple times

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I observe that the onUpdated listener for the tabs API in Chrome does trigger multiple times.

1. When I refresh the existing tab, the alert pops up 3 times
2. When I load a different URL, the alert pops up 4 times

In the alert popup, I also see that there seem to be "intermediate" title tags.

How can I avoid this and reduce action to the final update?

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
/* 
    Multiple Tasks:
    1.  Check whether title tag matches the CPD Teamcenter title and custom success tab does not exist
    2.  If yes, trigger three actions:
        a.  move tab to new Chrome window
        b.  call external application to hide the window with the isolated tab
        c.  add custom success tag to identify that this was already processed
*/

const COMPARESTRING = "My Tab Title"

var title = tab.title;
alert(title)  // this alert pops up 3 or 5 times!  


 /* if (title == COMPARESTRING) {
    return "Match. :-)";
} else {
    return "No match. :-(";
} */

});
```

Comment: onUpdated is called for many sub-events so add a check like `if (changeInfo.title)`

Comment: Or you can check `changeInfo.status === "complete"`

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, tabInfo, tab): void {
    if (tab.url !== undefined && tabInfo.status === "complete") {
         // do something - your logic
     };
});
```